# Difference between PHP and Java Unix Time Stamps

Tags: java, php, unix-timestamp

I have done this in Java:

```
Calendar lCDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
date = lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis();
```

I have done this in PHP:

```
  $date = date(U);
```

In Java, it is working. In PHP it doesn't.

In Java I get: `1358789604926`
In PHP I get: `1358790190`  (a smaller number)

Can anyone explain the difference between the two results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The timestamp generated by Java is in miliseconds, while the timestamp generated by PHP is in seconds. So in order to compare the two, you just need to "drop" the last three digits of the Java timestamp with division by 1000.

Comment: Perfect.  I actually NEED it in miliseconds.  So just times the PHP one by 1000 then.

Comment: @KickingLettuce, wouldn't be 100% accurate, but yes.

Comment: To get time in milliseconds in PHP, use `round(microtime(true)*1000)`

Answer (score 0):

The java result is the number of milliseconds since the start of the unix epoch in 01.01.1970, the second are the seconds.